# динамическое размещение графиков на странице

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Есть задача формировать графики (размер, положение и кол-во) с помощью пользовательского интерфейса. За аналогию взят map designer из PRGT.  Для построения графиков использую библиотеку canvas js. А вот с размещение на странице беда не знаю даже отчего отталкиваться. В каком направление начать движение что бы прийти к результату. [image: Map desinger]